# while loop error in Python

Tags: python

I'd appreciate some help debugging this code:

```
testing = """There is something unique about this line
in that it can span across several lines, which is unique and
useful in python."""

listofthings = []

i = 0
while i < len(testing):
    if testing[i] == " ":
        listofthings.append(i + 1)

    i = i + 1

listofthings.insert(0, 0)
listofthings.append(len(testing))

print listofthings

word_list = []

i = 0

while i < len(listofthings):
    l = i + 1
    x = listofthings[i]
    y = listofthings[l]

    word = testing[x:y]
    word_list.append(word)

    i = l

print word_list
```

I am not sure why I am getting the `index out of range` error.  I understand what the error means obviously, but am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Weirdly enough, this only happens when I run the above code.  It doesn't give me any errors when I run this:

```
word = testing[x:y]
print word
```

I am fairly new with Python(going on three days) so I am sure it is a stupid overlooked syntactical error...

Comment: If you want a loop that counts up to some number, you should use `for i in xrange(that_number)` instead of incrementing a counter variable manually. It's easier and less bug-prone. Of course, most of the time, what you really want to do is iterate over the elements of a thing, in which case you want `for element in thing`.

Comment: Yeh, I was using `for` but it kept throwing errors at me, so I switched it to while.  So, why is it working with print but not with the append?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of list `listofshit` is 21 with the range of index from 0 to 20. And when it comes to the final loop, `i` is 20 and `l` is 21, so there is a out of range error. And I think the following code is what you want:

```
testing = """There is something unique about this line
in that it can span across several lines, which is unique and
useful in python."""

listofshit = []

i = 0
while i < len(testing):
    if testing[i] == " ":
        listofshit.append(i)

    i = i + 1

listofshit.insert(0, 0)
listofshit.append(len(testing))


word_list = []
i = 0

while i < len(listofshit) - 1:
    l = i + 1
    x = listofshit[i]
    y = listofshit[l]
    word = testing[x:y]
    word_list.append(word)

    i = l

print word_list
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l = i + 1
x = listofshit[i]
y = listofshit[l]

word = testing[x:y]
word_list.append(word)
```

When `i=length-1`,then `y=length`, which is an error.Python array indexing starts from 0, hence max address is `length-1`

Comment: I know this might not be the most elegant way, but could i do something like this(after i = l): `if i > len(l): i -= 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
while i < len(listofshit):
    l = i + 1
    x = listofshit[i]
    y = listofshit[l]
```

When `i` corresponds to the last element,

```
    y = listofshit[l]
```

You are trying to access the element next to the last element. Thats why it is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

On the last iteration of the second while loop, `l` is set to `len(listofshit)`. This is past the end of `listofshit`; the last valid index is `len(listofshit) - 1`.